# Compare values of 2 sessions displaying blank page

Tags: php

I am trying to check whether either condition exists and if it al does then perform an action. However, what is happening is that the page is producing no errors just white page. There is nothing in the `php_error.log` or Apache so obviously my markup is incorrect. Here is a brief outline of what I am trying to achieve.

Firstly check that the user is logged in. If not then go to the header location.

Secondly check that the user is at the correct level to view the page. If not then send them to the header location.

Thirdly if both user is logged in and they have the correct level, (0 or 2) they can then view the page. If I remove the second if statement it works fine.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['ls_logged_usr']) {
header('Location: /mobile/index.php?error=NOLOGIN');
exit;
}
?>
<?php
if($_SESSION['ls_level_usr'] !== '0' || ($_SESSION['ls_level_usr'] !== '2') {
header('Location: /mobile/index.php?error=LEVELERROR');
exit;
}
//echo 'level: ' . $_SESSION['ls_level_usr'] . '<br />' . 'Active: ' . $_SESSION['ls_active_usr'];

?>
```

Comment: check if your `$_SESSION` vars exist, and put `error_reporting(0)` at the top of your PHP code to make sure it displays any error

Answer (score 1):

The header(...) function will add only some HTTP Headers. The current script will not be terminated.

To stop the current script after setting the header you have to write something like:

```
if(...) {
  header(...);
  exit;
}
if(...) ...
```

Comment: I have made changes as you suggested and amended my code but it still is not displaying. Thanks

Comment: No, @powerpete, `header("location: ...")` will redirect you to another page and forget all in previous page, so put something after `header("location: ...")` is useless

Answer (score 1):

I think, if that is all of your code, so it's OK, it means all of your condition are `false`

Try this

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION['ls_logged_usr']) {
        header('Location: /mobile/index.php?error=NOLOGIN');
    } 
    elseif($_SESSION['ls_level_usr'] != '0' || ($_SESSION['ls_level_usr'] != '2') {
        header('Location: /mobile/index.php?error=LEVELERROR');
    }

    // do something 

?>
```

I have changed your `!==` to `!=`

Comment: Still the same. How can I trouble shoot this. thanks

Comment: have you try my first comment of your question?

Comment: You mean the exit;? yeh i tried that and replied back. thanks

Comment: No, I repeat my comment here:  check if your `$_SESSION` vars exist, and put `error_reporting(0)` at the top of your PHP code to make sure it displays any error

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it using this code. Instead of using || I used && and it worked. need to get my head around the logic. My interpretation of OR is different to php's. Many thanks for all assistance given as usual here.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['ls_logged_usr'])) {
header('Location: /mobile/index.php?error=NOLOGIN');
exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (($_SESSION['ls_level_usr'] != '0') && ($_SESSION['ls_level_usr'] != '2')){
header('Location: /mobile/index.php?error=LEVELERROR');
exit;
}
?>
```